# JTable. How to stop rendering, fill it with data & then start rendering back?

Tags: swing, jtable

I have JTable. I need to fill it with data, set rows heights according to this data.
I want to stop rendering/packing before filling and start it back after.
How do I do it right?

Comment: What do you mean "stop rendering"? Like...you want it to become invisible? Or you don't want to update the table UI while you're in the middle of modifying the table model?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to update the table UI while I am in the middle of modifying the table model

Comment: why, what do you want to gain?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, which may or may not be overkill, is to set a new table [model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) that has the new data in it, then perform your table modifications, such as setting the row height.

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)